# variational characterization of convex projection

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $C$ be a nonempty closed convex subset of 
a real Hilbert space $X$, and let $x \in X$. 
Then there 
exists a unique point $P_{C}x \in C$ such that 
$\left\Vert x - P_{C}x \right\Vert 
= \min_{y \in C} \left\Vert x-y \right\Vert$.
Moreover, this point is characterized by
$$
P_{C}x \in C \quad \text{and}
\quad 
\left( \forall y \in C \right)
~
\left< x-P_{C}x ~ , ~ y-P_{C}x \right> \leq 0.
$$
I happened to know that
this characterization is (or was)
known as the Bourbaki-Cheney-Goldstein
inequality
and started to look around 
for book references but could not
find one.
(This characterization is 
known to me as 
"obtuse angle criterion"
or "projection theorem.")

My question is: 
Is there any book that refers to 
the above characterization as 
"Bourbaki-Cheney-Goldstein"?
I am curious about this
and it would be nice to
know the reason behind this name.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What characterization ?  do you want to know if inquality holds the point is projection point , right? cant you prove it by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to that book written by P.G.Ciarlet, *Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications*, Theorem 4.3-1.